# Chatbot using dash python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

i want to create a chatbot using dash.Is it possible to create a chatbot using dash?
Chatbot logic completed but i want to implement chatbot look in web browser.In html we have container to create a dialog flow of chatbot.Like in html i have to get user input from textbox to container's body and system responses in container's body in dash.

present output:

[image]

Expected output:

Is it possible to create like below image look in dash?

[image]

suggest me ideas.

Comment: How about this?: https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/main/apps/dash-gpt3-chatbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** (Using Dash)

Refer this [link](https://github.com/AdamSpannbauer/app_rasa_chat_bot) that shows a demo implementation of chatbot in dash that you are looking for. This demo app shows the history of user conversations as you wanted.

**Option 2:** (Using Flask)

When you opt for native flask implementation rather than dash, you can get many sample implementations of chatbots with the features you are looking for. Refer below links:

https://dev.to/sahilrajput/build-a-chatbot-using-flask-in-5-minutes-574i

https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/building-a-machine-learning-chat-bot-with-flask-framework-and-python-2c24b2def49b

Comment: I tried with flask but it is not taking responses from logic to display in web browser.

Comment: @Magie Should be a problem with your code. Please post your code along with current results and expected results. The links that are shown in the answer do have the feature of taking responses from logic I suppose.

Comment: I saw those links provided by you.They using maching learning algorithm and using chatterbot package.But my chatbot is based on intelligence string matching without using chatterbot package and machine learning algorithm.

Comment: If you don't mind can you see my previous question,There i used flask framework.

Comment: Dear @Magie - Though the samples are on chatterbot package and ML algorithms, when it comes to Dash or Flask framework, your issue was you weren't able to achieve the interface you provided in the image in your question. You can use the code for the front end interface from those examples(i.e. for achieving the UI functionalities). When it comes to program logic, you can handle the responses from the interface either through ML algorithms or through your own intelligence string matching as you described. You are free to design your own code inside app callback to handle the responses from UI.